# How to get equivalent of Google Chrome "receiving time" of request in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

How to get this Receiving time/Loading Time in JMeter?

[image: This is snapshot of Chrome]

This is snapshot of Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand receiving time as time between last received byte and first received byte (not page loading time which included time for browser to interpret response) so this should be:

- [Elapsed Time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) -  [Latency](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

**Elapsed time.** JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.

**Latency.** JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analyzers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.

But I didn't find definition of Receiving time:

- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: Ok Thanks you are right about receiving time I had also resolved myself after posting this question. but I am now confuse whith your this sentence that response receiving time is not equal to Loading Time. Please tell me then what is loading time and also tell if u can  what is Rendering Time? what is the difference between both.

Comment: As I don't find definition of Google Chrome I cannot tell what is Loading time but I tend to think it is Elapsed time + Rendering Time (rendering being the time spent on browser to render page). Although browser is able to start rendering while still receiving so it is not that simple. Anyway JMeter is not concerned about rendering time.

Comment: Yes thanks for more information about render time. and Loading time is still a mystery from my side :(